# What is a good solution for providing icons to IE with font downloads disabled?

Tags: css, fonts

The site I'm currently developing uses Bootstrap's glyphicons for icons. I've just discovered that the site will be used in places where font downloading is disabled (users with IE11 which implements a group security policy). Given that I need to display these icons and that enabling font downloads is not an option I'm looking for ways I can do this. At the moment I see 2 options:

1. Remove the font icons and replace them with an image sprite
2. Use conditional comments (do these even work with IE11?) to provide an IE11 specific fallback

Is there anything else I can do in this situation or am I limited to those 2 choices?

Answer (score 0):

My goto Workflow is using SVG sprites.
Here is my setup:

- Optimize Icons using SVGO (https://github.com/svg/svgo)
- Creat SVG Sprite using SVGStore (https://github.com/w0rm/gulp-svgstore)
- Embed SVG via SVG tag
- Use SVG4Everybody (https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) to allow Cross Origin Requests

I use a gulp task to take care of it.

gulpfile.js

```
import gulp         from 'gulp';
import gulpSvgmin   from 'gulp-svgmin';
import gulpSvgstore from 'gulp-svgstore';

const dirs = {
  source: './source',
  dest  : './dist'
};

gulp.task('svg:icons', () => {
  return gulp.src(`${dirs.source}/assets/images/icons/**/*.svg`)
    .pipe(gulpSvgmin())
    .pipe(gulpSvgstore())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dirs.dest}/assets/images`));
});
```

index.html

```
<svg class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="assets/images/icons.svg#ICON_ID"></use></svg>

<script src="path/to/svg4everybody.js"></script>
```

This works pretty well and allows you to style your icons via CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I like the look of this and I'll be giving it a go.